# How do I call a function for 3 buttons all at once in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am not familiar with VBA. How do I call a function that calls 3 buttons all at once. The three buttons are already working but how do I call them to all work at once. I have done the below:

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
   Call Command1_Click()
   Call Command2_Click()
   Call Command3_Click()
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd say that's probably what you want. Or what do you mean with _at once_?

Comment: There are 3 buttons that perform 3 tasks separately. I want to create one button that will run all the 3 tasks on one click. I am not at all familiar with VBA. So I wasn't sure if I was doing that correctly in the function above. But if there is a better approach, that would be great.

Comment: But the code above will perform the code triggered when you click the three buttons one after each other. So, it will do what you are after.

Comment: sure, the above is fine - about the most practical way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take de code on each CommandButton_Click and past in to a Sub, so when you clic button1 calls Sub What_Button1_does, and in MasterButton you call all Subs

```
Private Sub MasterButton_Click()
    What_Button1_does
    What_Button2_does
    What_Button3_does
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    What_Button1_does

End Sub

Sub What_Button1_does

    (code from CommandButton1_Clic)

End sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Like the comments said that should work but, if you are looking for a simulated event. This is what it should look like I think.

```
Private Sub MasterButton_Click()
    CommandButton1.Value = True
    CommandButton2.Value = True
    CommandButton3.Value = True
End Sub
```

Though, I would suggest that you make some new methods and have each button call those methods. Then have the master button use all those methods/subs.

As Albert pointed out this doesn't work in Access? It works in excel and word. So ya the only way is to call the click method itself as well as using Call MasterButton_Click()

Comment: Above does not even compile in VBA. There is no "value" property of a VBA button on a Access form.

Comment: I edited the answer didn't realize that Access doesn't allow this.

Comment: No worries - flipping between VB net, c#, VBA, and JavaScript all day long? Often forget. And with user forms in Excel - I believe your code works - but not for access forms and buttons

Comment: And switching from vb6 sometimes T_T haha.